# Density heatmap computation

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, stat-density2d

I am trying to plot a positional heatmap using ggplot2, faceted by day of the week.  My dataset is quite large and computation is extremely slow.
I started by trying

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + facet_wrap(~day) + 
stat_density_2d(geom="raster", aes(fill=..density.., alpha=..density..))
```

However I realised that this was going to take ages so instead tried

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + facet_wrap(~day) + 
stat_density_2d(geom="polygon", n=10, aes(fill=..level.., alpha=..level))
```

But this still takes far too long to produce.

What is the best approach for this with large datasets?

Comment: What is large? Good solutions are to sample a smaller set, or to pre-calculate the densities before plotting.

Comment: Each facet had around 100,000 datapoints . How would one go about pre calculating the densities before plotting?